# Moodle PDF library | Certificate plugin

Tags: php, pdf, fonts, moodle

I want to create custom look of certificate in the `Certificate` `plugin` of `Moodle`. 
The problem is, that using `text` from some `variable`, the `line spacing` of the text can be set only until certain number (not close enough). The text is printed here:

```
certificate_print_text($pdf, $x, 140, 'L', 'Helvetica', '', 10, $seminar->details);
```

I have the same problem, when printing `PDF` with the `course information` on the `course page`. Tried to use `CSS`, but it won't work.

Are they any `limitation` of the `TCPDF` library of Moodle? If I am not wrong, they are also `limited` `fonts`, which we can use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the TCPDF documentation - http://www.tcpdf.org/docs.php . Adding extra fonts is covered in http://www.tcpdf.org/fonts.php

Comment: Thanks, I just checked it. What could be the reason for the line spacing restriction,that I am facing? It won't set it to the minimun?